# Is there a DI container that allows the use of "child scopes"?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Is there any .NET DI container that has a concept of "child scopes"?

Something like:

```
var container = AppConfiguredContainer();

using(var childContainer = container.GetChild())
{
  childContainer.Register<IFoo>(typeof(Foo));

  // do stuff with childContainer
}
```

The point is that any configuration of services done in the child container would not affect the application-wide configuration.

Comment: Try Ninject - not 100% sure about it though.

Comment: Unity - [using child containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec25)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Most containers have a feature call 'scoped lifestyle', which has the same effect in in most cases. And for the rest of the cases: you shouldn't be doing any registrations after the startup phase of the application. I even read a blog post from Krzysztof Koźmic that he regret ever having added this feature to Castle Windsor, so I think such feature is really questionable.

Comment: What you seem to want is registering a type with the lifetime of the child scope. This is exactly what a scoped lifestyle allows you to do. Most containers support this.

Comment: @Steven, if you can give an example with NInject, please do so and I'll accept your answer. What I'm trying to do, it like you say, register a type only for the lifetime of the scope because the registration does not apply for the rest of the application, only for that scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of child scopes binding with NInject:

```
var k = new StandardKernel();
k.Bind<Application>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope().DefinesNamedScope("Application");
k.Bind<UserRepository>().ToSelf().InNamedScope("Application");

const string userScopeName = "User";
k.Bind<UserScope>().ToSelf().DefinesNamedScope(userScopeName);
k.Bind<User>().ToSelf().InNamedScope(userScopeName);
k.Bind<User.ChatService>().ToSelf().InNamedScope(userScopeName);
k.Bind<User.SheetService>().ToSelf().InNamedScope(userScopeName);

const string nestedScopeName = "UserSheet";
k.Bind<User.Sheet>().ToSelf().DefinesNamedScope(nestedScopeName);
k.Bind<User.Sheet.SheetInfo>().ToSelf().InNamedScope(nestedScopeName);
k.Bind<User.Sheet.SheetCalculator>().ToSelf().InNamedScope(nestedScopeName);
```

You need to reference `Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope` and `Ninject.Extensions.Factory` with `Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservatioon`.

Each `Repository` may load multiple users and each of them will have multiple `Sheets` in "sub-scopes":

```
public class UserRepository
{
    Func<UserScope> _factory;

    [Inject]
    public UserRepository(Func<UserScope> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public UserScope LoadUser()
    {
        return _factory(); // scopes preserved
    }
}


public class User
{
    Func<Sheet> _sheetFactory; // multiple instances inside User scope
    public UserRepository Repository { get; } // same instance for app
    [Inject]
    public User(Func<Sheet> sheetFactory, UserRepository repository)
    {
        Repository = repository;
        _sheetFactory = sheetFactory;
    }

    public Sheet MakeSheet()
    {
        return _sheetFactory();
    }
}
```

It's important to use `UserScope` class as a container for `User` because otherwise you can't resolve the same instance of `User` from inside its dependencies:

```
public class UserScope : IDisposable
{
    [Inject]
    public UserScope(User user, IResolutionRoot resolver)
    {
        User = user;
        Resolver = resolver;
    }

    public User User { get; }
    public IResolutionRoot Resolver { get; } // you can use this to resolve anything from inside **this** user scope
}
```

Then you can load users like:

```
var app = k.Get<Application>(); // singleton
var u1 = app.Repository.LoadUser();
var u2 = app.Repository.LoadUser();
```

And each of them will have the same instances of `Application` and `Repository` but different instances of `ChatService` and `SheetService`.